# Folland Exercise 7.18 on Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I'm trying to do the exercise below.

> **18.** If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure on $X$ and $\nu \in \mathcal{M}(X)$, let $\nu=\nu_1+\nu_2$ be the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. Then $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are Radon. (Use Exercise 8.)

Also, can we say that $\| v\| = \|v_1\| + \| v_2\|$?

Here $M(X)$ is the space of complex Radon measures on $X$, and if $\mu \in M(X)$, we define $\|\mu \| = |\mu|(X)$, where $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

I know that by Lebesgue decomposition we have $v_1 \ll \mu$ and $v_2 \perp \mu$. By the Radon- Nikodym theorem,  there exists some $f \in L^+$ such that $v_1(E) = \int_E f d\mu$ for $E \in B_X.$ By exercise 8, we have $v_1$ is Radon.

But from here, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What's $\mathcal{M}(X)$ here?  If it's just something like "finite measures", this doesn't seem to be true; what if we take $\nu$ non-Radon and $\mu = 0$?  (Actually the errata says it should be $M(X)$ but what is that?)

Comment: On the other hand if $\nu$ is in fact a finite (or signed or complex) Radon measure, just write $\nu_2 = \nu - \nu_1$ and use the fact that the signed/complex Radon measures form a vector space.

Comment: Here $M(X)$ is the space of complex Radon measures on $X$, and if $\mu \in M(X)$, we define $\|\mu \| = |\mu|(X)$, where $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

Comment: @Catcher why doesn't Nate's second comment answer the question?

Comment: Note that the version of the Radon-Nikodym theorem you want here would give $f \in L^1(\mu)$, not $L^+$.

Comment: Typographical note, that's a letter nu, not v.  $\nu$ not $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you have that $\nu, \nu_1$ are both complex Radon measures (i.e. they are in $M(X)$) and that $\nu= \nu_1 + \nu_2$, which is to say $\nu_2 = \nu - \nu_1$.  Now Proposition 7.16 says that $M(X)$ is a vector space, so it follows that $\nu_2 \in M(X)$ as well, i.e. $\nu_2$ is Radon.

To see that $\|\nu\| = \|\nu_1\| + \|\nu_2\|$, note we have disjoint measurable sets $E_1, E_2$ such that $|\nu_1|(E_2) = |\nu_2|(E_1) = 0$.  Let $f_i = d\nu_i/d|\nu|$ for $i=1,2$.  Show that on the one hand, $|f_1 + f_2|= 1$, $|\nu|$-a.e.  On the other hand, show that the set $\{f_1 \ne 0\} \cap \{f_2 \ne 0\}$ is $|\nu|$-null, and conclude that $|f_1 + f_2| = |f_1| + |f_2|$, $|\nu|$-a.e.  Now note that $\|\nu_i\| = \int |f_i|\,d|\nu|$ and so on.

Comment: Can we say that $\| v\| = \|v_1\| + \| v_2\|$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, that should not be hard to prove; where did you get stuck?

Comment: It's straight forward that we have $\| v\| \leq \|v_1 \| + \|v_2\|$. I'm stuck on the other direction...